# XeTeX big and small delimiter

Tags: fonts, xetex, delimiters

I saw, that in `plain.tex` file, the delimiters are defines two characters at once. However for Plain XeTeX `\XeTeXdelimiter` macro description in the documentation only states one character. However I understand, that `\delimiter` is defining these character for a big and small alternative. Is it possible to define the same with `\XeTeXdelimiter`?

The reason that I ask this, is that when I write `\left|f(x)\right|` for instance, then the U+FFFD character appears, instead of something like a big vertical line or bar, when I use Cambria Math. How to define what character to display for `\left|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the delimiter code for the vertical bar using \XeTeXdelcode. Away from my machine at present so I can't give an example, sorry.

Comment: You're right! When I wrote my definitions, I simply skipped the delcode definitions. (The < > | and \ delcodes does not match the actual code in the character table.)